# How do i add code completion for angular2 addons like font awesome?

Tags: angular, webstorm, font-awesome, angular-cli

I have the following angular-cli.json file for my Angular2 application. I am able to load bootstrap and font awesome in my project, however i do not get code completion.

```
    {
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
    "name": "web"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "./../node_modules/ng2-toasty/style-material.css",
        "./../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "./../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": ["../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*.+(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)"],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

How do i enable code completion for font awesome icons?